# Maps to additive group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

Let $\underline{\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p}$ be constant p-divisible group over $\mathbb{F}_p$. And let $\mathbb{G}_a$ be the additive group over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let me prove

$$
Hom(\underline{\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p},\mathbb{G}_a)=0
$$

Indeed, Since $p=0$, we have $\mathbb{G}_a=\mathbb{G}_a[p]$ so multiplying by $p$ is zero map for $\mathbb{G}_a$, for any $f\in Hom(\underline{\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p},\mathbb{G}_a)$, the following diagram commutes,
$\require{AMScd}$

\begin{CD}
\underline{\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p}@>f>>\mathbb{G}_a\\
@Vp(\cong) VV @Vp=0VV\\
\underline{\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p}@>f>>\mathbb{G}_a\\
\end{CD}

therefore the statement follows.

**However**, I heared that 
$$
Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)=Lie_{G^*}
$$

So $Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)$ should be tangent space for the dual of $\underline{\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p}$, which is $\mathbb{G}_m[p^\infty]$, but in this case, the tagenet space of it is non-zero.

## What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand now, the equation

$$
Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)=0
$$

is correct for p-divisible groups over a ring where $p$ is nilpotent, but 
$$
Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)=Lie_{G^*}
$$
is only true for **FINITE FLAT GROUP SCHEMES**. This is no longer true for p-divisible groups.

Because here $G^*$ is defined as to represent the $Hom(G,G_m)$, if $G$ is p-divisible, this functor may be not representable. In fact, the dual of p-divisible group is defined by other way, it is not a Cartier Dual.